# Fedora, fsck fails at boot

Tags: linux, raid, filesystems, fedora, mdadm

I'm facing a problem in my server during the startup. This is my actual configuration:

```
320GB each. Raid1 -> /dev/md127. Working.
/dev/sda
/dev/sdc

1000GB each. Raid1 -> Use to be /dev/md126, now it is /dev/md1. AFAIK, it works properly
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdd

2000GB -> Started to show some bad-functioning symptons. Now is disconnected
/dev/sde
```

This are the actual errors i got:

```
fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
The superblock could not be read or does nor describe a correct ext2 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>


fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1:
The superblock could not be read or does nor describe a correct ext2 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Then, i can press CTRL+D and system got rebooted, or enter root password and be dropped to a shell with this prompt -> "(Repair filesystem) 1:"

With the /dev/md126 AKA /dev/md1 there is no problem, because from this shell, i can mount /dev/md1 and have access to the data.

With the /dev/sde1, i dont know why the error occurs since the disk is disconnected.

Both devices (md126 and sde1) are included in /etc/fstab, but from the shell, seems like all the filesystem are read-only, so i cant modify fstab file.

Any ideas of what can i do? Im kind of lost now.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
From the "Repair filesystem" shell, i can replicate the error messages doing "fsck -A -y", so it walk through all the etc/fstab file cheking each entry, but as i said, the filesystem is "read-only", so i cant change the file.

About the old /etc/md126 AKA /etc/md1 array that i can mount perfectly from the shell, if i make a fdisk on the 2 disk that compoes the array i get this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, xxxxxxx bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors....
Units= sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (min/optimal) = 4096/4096
**Disk identifier: 0x00000000**

Disk /dev/sdb doesnt contain a valid partition table

[And exactly the same for /dev/sdd]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your `/etc/fstab`.  While it contains entries telling the OS that it should find and mount `/dev/md126` and `/dev/sde1` on boot, the OS won't be happy.

Either boot from rescue media and modify the entry, or boot, fix the root filesystem, do `mount -o remount,rw /` and modify the entry.

Once that `fstab` entry says `/dev/md1` in place of `/dev/md126`, and says nothing about `/dev/sde1`, your boot sequence should be much less painful.

Comment: mount -o remount,rw --> That was the key! After remounting with rw, i edited fstab and everything works

Comment: Glad to hear you're up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Fedora system is using GRUB at boot time, edit the kernel parameters to skip `fsck` when booting:

- Edit the Fedora entry in the GRUB menu at boot by pressing <kbd>e</kbd>
- Then edit its corresponding `kernel` line by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on it
- Append the word `fastboot` at the end of the line and press <kbd>b</kbd>
- Boot into Fedora by skipping `fsck` on erroneous filesystems

Now you can fix the real problem, which seems to be related to a wrong partition table or corrupt filesystem on your disk. Also, if in doubt, run [`smartctl`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Smartctl) on your disk to diagnose it physically.